# IncompatibleClassChangeError on Android Things

Tags: android-things

After updating to the latest Android Things preview, my app is crashing when
setting a callback on by button GPIO. I have the following button callback defined:

```
private class ButtonCallback extends GpioCallback {
    @Override
    public boolean onGpioEdge(Gpio gpio) {
        boolean isPressed = false;
        try {
            isPressed = gpio.getValue();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error", e);
        }

        if (isPressed) {
            ...
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am registering it with the GPIO in the application as follows:

```
Gpio button = ...;
try {
    button.registerGpioCallback(new ButtonCallback());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Error configuring GPIO pins", e);
}
```

When I run my app, I get an `IncompatibleClassChangeError` and the app crashes:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Superclass com.google.android.things.pio.GpioCallback of com.google.android.things.example.MainActivity$ButtonCallback is an interface (...)
```

This code was working before, why has this started happening after the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in Preview 7, many of the Peripheral I/O interfaces were converted from
abstract classes to interfaces. This was done to better facilitate testability
in apps, as interfaces are easier to mock.

Be sure to update your app to use the Preview 7 SDK:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.7-devpreview'
}
```

Then modify your callback to implement the interface instead:

```
private class ButtonCallback implements GpioCallback {
    @Override
    public boolean onGpioEdge(Gpio gpio) {
        boolean isPressed = false;
        try {
            isPressed = gpio.getValue();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error", e);
        }

        if (isPressed) {
            ...
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Review the Android Things [API reference](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/index.html)
to verify if any of the other APIs you are calling have changed.